# Выражение "закадычный друг"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда произошло выражение "закадычный друг" и что оно означает?

"Закадычный" обычно связывают с "кадык". Как объяснить эту связь?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В прошлые века в русском языке существовало устойчивое выражение "заливать за кадык", то есть пить алкоголь. Поэтому "закадычным другом" называли фактически собутыльника, того, с кем можно выпить.

Потом этот фразеологизм стал употребляться в более широком смысле, обозначая близкую дружбу.

Answer (score 2):

Это слово есть у Шанского в словаре: Закадычный Искон. Суф. производное от (залить) за кадык «напиться». Исходное значение — «собутыльник» > «задушевный

Answer (score 0):

Закадычный друг — это собутыльник. Никакого широкого смысла тут нет. А тот, кто использует это выражение в широком смысле, пусть обратится к другим словам русского языка, коих немало.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, когда говорят, что вон Петя — мой закадычный дружок, то подразумевают именно собутыльника и веселого друга, с которым не одна бутылка  алкоголя распита.

Но вот совсем  не  по-русски сказать: это — моя закадычная подружка. Оно понятно, что нынешние девушки тоже не прочь залить за воротник. Но вот всё же не комильфо так о близкой подруге говорить.

Эта идиома — *закадычный* — исключительно мужского рода (и пола, соответственно).